# I want to use a literal "FILE" in Java as a storage point for the data contained in a file system file

Tags: java, database, file, object, db4o

I am building a database using db4o that contains files and information about the files, but want to do so in a way that does not require a file system behind it (I specifically want a file system to not exist because of the complexity of the file relations: there would be no way to design such a file system in an intelligent way for the web of items we work with.)

So I know that the `File` class is a pointer to a file in a file system, but I want the actual file to be encompassed in the object I'm working with. I would use a string, but the objects can often be load binaries, images, or movies, so that would be a misuse of the type that I do not want.

I have been searching quite a bit, but haven't found a solution and most of my searches just lead me to explanations of the `File` class.

Example object I want:

```
public class FileContainer {
    private Date addedDate;
    private String checkSum;
    private Boolean criticalState;
    private FileContainer previousVersion;
    private String addedBy;
    private FileObject file;
}
```

where the FileObject is simply the actual file.

Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about using a byte array?

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 7 you can have artificial file systems, like the [ZipFileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/zipfilesystemprovider.html), which is very near to what you want. In fact adding a file, removing a file, renaming a file, maintaining relative paths between two file systems. All such examples would be usable for your file system too.

Also the new nio API can provide file attributes by free key.

The advantage is using one generic API for all file systems. The class `Path` also holds its file system for instance.